# how to make a tooltip for java plugins text

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to make a tooltip for a Minecraft plugin text so when hover it shows the hi on the tool I keep seeing people using out of date resources and I can't find any new this on the Webb

```
package ga.harrytubestudios.helloworld.commands;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import ga.harrytubestudios.helloworld.main;

public class hellocomamnd implements CommandExecutor {

    private main plugin;
    
    public hellocomamnd(main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("hello").setExecutor(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
if (!(sender instanceof Player)){
    sender.sendMessage("player only command");
    return true;

}
Player p = (Player) sender ;

    p.sendMessage("hi");
    return true;
    

    }
}
```

please help me I can't find any help and I hope this can help any one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's this format built into the spigot

```
TextComponent test= new TextComponent("hi");
    shopfood.setHoverEvent(new HoverEvent(HoverEvent.Action.SHOW_TEXT,new ComponentBuilder("hi")).create() ));
p.spigot().sendMessage(test);
```

some sample code and it will so some text when hover on the text and heres the anwser

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
if (!(sender instanceof Player)){
    sender.sendMessage("player only command");
    return true;

}
Player p = (Player) sender ;
TextComponent test= new TextComponent("hi");
    shopfood.setHoverEvent(new HoverEvent(HoverEvent.Action.SHOW_TEXT,new ComponentBuilder("hi")).create() ));
p.spigot().sendMessage(test);
    return true;


    }
}
```

here's some sample code

```
TextComponent enter-var-name-here = new TextComponent(enter first text);
    shopfood.setHoverEvent(new HoverEvent(HoverEvent.Action.SHOW_TEXT,new ComponentBuilder(enter-hover-text)).create() ));
p.spigot().sendMessage(enter-var-name-here);
```